# Windows 10 Stuck on loading Screen after Enabling VT-x

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, virtualization

I'm trying to enable Intel Virtualization on my PC through BIOS but, every time I do it boots to the windows Logo and is stuck there with no white loading circle animation just the logo and that's it. Any advice would be much appreciated. Also tried "Cold boot" not sure if I did it correctly but, just wanted to inform that I did try just in case.

I don't have **Hyper - V** enabled it never was checked when I searched to see if it was enabled.

My System:

- Intel i7-5960X
- Asus Tuff Sabertooth x99 Motherboard
- 32 GB  Corsair Platinum Ram
- Titan X Maxwell GPU
- Windows 10 version 2004

Comment: @john So I fixed it i went back into enabled VT didn't see the hardware VT you mentioned under **CPU Settings** and just started looking and found **VT-d** under **system configuration** (which come to  think of it maybe that's the Hardware VT you are mentioning) was disabled Enabled now works

Comment: @john yeah i just enabled both and it worked

Comment: @John - I don't understand your last comment.  `Intel Hardware Virtualization` actually is `VT-X` while VT-d is `Intel Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O` which allows a virtual machine to use or have access to a physical device.  VT-d isn't required by Hyper-V/VirtualBox/VMWare unless you are attempting to do something very specific.  Likewise, VT-x is only required if you are attempting to install a 64-bit operating system on the VM (or using Android Studio/ect).

Comment: @Ramhound My main purpose for Enabling VT is for Android Emulation it said I need VT to make it run better. I enabled it by itself and it wouldn't work. Now when I enabled VT-d and VT it works. Do I only need just one of the 2?

Comment: Android Studio doesn’t use VT-d

Comment: @Ramhound so i need normal VT then

Comment: @Ramhound also im using Bluestacks and Nox Player

Comment: Let me put it this way, the products you are using, only use VT-x

Comment: @Ramhound Okay so then again to my predicament. Why when I enable VT in CPU Settings in BIOS I'm stuck in boot Windows Logo indefinitely. Then when I enable both VT-x and VT-d it works. If I can find the solution to just the VT-x then I will just disable VT-d